Putting variable data into one single file
I'm hoping there is a better way to do this...
I have a series of applications that use their own YAML files. Each YAML file is specific to each application. Then I have several environments that use these same YAML files but with tweaks specific to that environment.
I would like to generate those YAML files from a common template specific for each application. Each YAML files has redundant data. I am trying to have one file for each environment with the variable data in it specific to each environment.
Template YAML file:
HostIP: << HOST_IP >>

variables file:
HOST_IP="192.168.1.1"

BASH script:
source ./variables.inc
cp app1.yaml.TEMPLATE app1.yaml
sed -i "s/<< HOST_IP >>/$HOST_IP/g" app1.yaml

This works, but I keep thinking there has to be a better way.

Rather than cp followed by sed -i, just use sed.  The -i option to sed is an abomination, but you seem to be going out of your way to use it!

There are a lot of configuration languages to choose from (you might consider making your own!), but using sed to replace values is not actually too terrible.

You can use envsubst, jinja2, m4, php, cpp . There are many template langauges.

IFS= read -rd '' template < app1.yaml.TEMPLATE; printf %s "${template//<< HOST_IP >>/$HOST_IP}" > app1.yaml

Use a language that actually understands YAML instead of bash.

Do you try to use a specialized tool like yq? HOST_IP="192.168.1.2" yq --null-input '.HostIP = strenv(HOST_IP)'

If you store the template YAML files (with or without the parts to be modified), and override YAML files, you can merge them in various ways.
There are many YAML tools that can do this. (e.g. yq; yaml-merge; config-merge; yaml-updater; YAML Path and Command-Line Tools)
For example, to merge with Mike Farah's yq:
$ cat template.yml
a:
  b:
    c: original
    d: original
e:
  f: original
$ cat override.yml
a:
  b:
    c: updated
g:
  h: new
$ yq eval-all 'select(fi==0) * select(fi==1)' template.yml override.yml
a:
  b:
    c: updated
    d: original
e:
  f: original
g:
  h: new
$

If replacements are used in multiple places, yq also has envsubst
$ cat template.yml
a:
  b:
    c: foo ${var1}
    d: bar $var3
e:
  f: ${var2}
  g: $var4
$ cat override.sh
# note that this is actually a full shell script
var1='altered value'
var2='also altered'
var3="'"'multiple
     lines
[ !@#$%^&*()-=_+,.<>:;"\| ]
'"'"
var4='x:
  y: hmmm...'
$ ( set -a; . override.sh;
    yq '(..|select(tag=="!!str")) |= envsubst' template.yml
  )
a:
  b:
    c: foo altered value
    d: |-
      bar 'multiple
           lines
      [ !@#$%^&*()-=_+,.<>:;"\| ]
      '
e:
  f: also altered
  g: |-
    x:
      y: hmmm...
$

